# Get each column which contains multiple spaces?

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

My file:

```
subnet 172.25.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
option domain-name-servers 172.25.10.9, 8.8.8.8;
default-lease-time 300;
max-lease-time 7500;
range dynamic-bootp 172.25.10.10 172.25.10.30 ;
option broadcast-address 172.25.10.255;
option routers 172.25.10.1;
option ip-forwarding off;
}
```

for each field I want the `text part` alone and the `value part` alone:( I don't know the fields and how many spaces in each one, the same thing for values)

as we notice:

Fields:

```
max-lease-time;(o space)
option domain-name-servers (1 space)
```

Values:

```
300(o space)

172.25.10.10 172.25.10.30 ( 1 space)
```

My desired outpput is:

I want to put the values in a variables named after the fields:

```
domain-name-servers="172.25.10.9, 8.8.8.8"(eliminate `option`)
default-lease-time="300"
```

and so on

`awk` won't work for me, because there are some values with spaces: `172.25.10.9, 8.8.8.8`

can I reach my goal using `grep -o`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can substitute an `=` using grep where it doesn't exist in the original text; however assuming your version of grep supports the PCRE extensions you could separate the name-value pairs as follows

```
grep -oP '(option |range )?\K(\S+) (.+?(?=;))'
```

If you want the substitution, you could use plain perl instead e.g.

```
perl -pe 's/(option |range )?(\S+) (.+?);/$2="$3"/' file
subnet 172.25.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
domain-name-servers="172.25.10.9, 8.8.8.8"
default-lease-time="300"
max-lease-time="7500"
dynamic-bootp="172.25.10.10 172.25.10.30 "
broadcast-address="172.25.10.255"
routers="172.25.10.1"
ip-forwarding="off"
}
```

[You're not specific about what you want to do with the opening and closing lines, so I just left them as-is]

or, more-or-less equivalently with sed

```
sed -E 's/(option |range )?([^[:space:]]{1,}) (.*);/\2="\3"/' file
```

both of which break the expression up into 3 *groups* consisting of, respectively

- optional string consisting of `options` or `range` followed by a single space
- a non-empty sequence of non-space characters (followed by a single space)
- zero or more characters (followed by `;`)

and then substitute back only the second and third groups, with the `=` sign and added double quotes. In a real application you should probably try to make these expressions more robust for example by replacing any single spaces by non-zero length sequences of POSIX `[[:space:]]` characters (i.e. spaces and/or tabs).

**Note that in all cases it is assumed that only the `value` fields may contain spaces; the `name` fields (like `default-lease-time`) are assumed to consist of non-whitespace characters. I don't think there is a *lexical* way of handling the case where *both* fields may contain arbitrary unquoted whitespace.**

Comment: I have added some explanation plus a possible `sed` alternative